# imperfect parsing with pdfminer3k

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert .pdf files to .txt files,
however I got a problem.
Here's My python code.

```
for i in flist:
    newFile = ''
    if i.endswith('py'): continue
    if i.find('.h') != -1:
        newFile = i.replace('.h.pdf','.h')
    else:
        newFile = i.replace('.pdf','.txt') 
    os.system("python pdf2txt.py -o %s %s" % (newFile, i))
```

This code converts pdf files to txt files, however, 
output txt files are imperfectly parsed.
Do you know why it parsed imperfectly?

Comment: Can you explain what's not parsed correctly?

Comment: You need check the `pdf2txt.py` file. The code you paste just get the file list, the convert process in `pdf2txt.py`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It can't parse sort of strings and tables. I need to check pdf2txt.py.